# Is there a utility class to convert an ASP.NET Request object to a string aka dump it?

Tags: asp.net, logging, request

I'm writing a logging component and one of my methods I want to implement is being able to dump the information from an ASP.NET request object (Session variables, POST\GET variables, Custom Headers, URL from request, authorized user, client ip, etc).  Rather then writing code to parse this information out of the request object, I was wondering if there was a utility class to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at serializing the object but that's going to be overkill. Better to just log the pieces of data **you** need.

Answer (score 0):

I guess its a good fit for ASP.NET HttpModule. You can find more information about HttpModule at http://www.csharpfriends.com/articles/getarticle.aspx?articleid=268

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)

You should consider using this instead of rolling your own.
It provides a ready to use interface and is very simple to setup